# Pandas -- Replace dirty strings with int

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I am trying to do some machine learning practice, but the ID column of my dataframe is giving me trouble. I have this:

```
0    LP001002
1    LP001003
2    LP001005
3    LP001006
4    LP001008
```

I want this:

```
0    001002
1    001003
2    001005
3    001006
4    001008
```

My idea is to use a `replace` function, `ID.replace('[LP]', '', inplace=True)`, but this doesn't actually change the series. Any one know a good way to convert this column?

Comment: change it to `'LP'`?

Comment: First thing I tried; it had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace`

```
df
Out[656]: 
        Val
0  LP001002
1  LP001003
2  LP001005
3  LP001006
4  LP001008
df.Val.replace({'LP':''},regex=True)
Out[657]: 
0    001002
1    001003
2    001005
3    001006
4    001008
Name: Val, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that will work for the example as given:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'colname': ['LP001002', 'LP001003']})

# Slice off the 0th and 1st character of the string
df['colname'] = [x[2:] for x in df['colname']]
```

If this is your index, you can access it through `df['my_index'] = df.index` and then follow the remaining instructions.

In general, you might consider using something like the [label encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) from scikit learn to convert nonnumeric elements to numeric ones.